# Cannot read exit_code after main in destructor

Tags: c, linux

I am using LD_PRELOAD to wrap executables and want to record the exit code. In the destructor I am reading the /proc/self/stat file that includes the exit code, but it is always zero. Here is the code I am using, but without a preload.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int get_exit_code()
{
    int exit_code = 0;
    FILE *file = fopen("/proc/self/stat", "rt");
    if (file) {
        char *line = 0;
        size_t line_len = 0;
        if (getline(&line, &line_len, file) != -1) {
            sscanf(line, "%*d %*s %*c %*d %*d %*d %*d %*d %*u %*u "
                         "%*u %*u %*u %*u %*u %*d %*d %*d %*d %*d "
                         "%*d %*u %*u %*d %*u %*u %*u %*u %*u %*u "
                         "%*u %*u %*u %*u %*u %*u %*u %*d %*d %*u "
                         "%*u %*u %*u %*d %*u %*u %*u %*u %*u %*u "
                         "%*u %d",
                         &exit_code);
        }
        free(line);
        fclose(file);
    }
    return exit_code;
}

int main(void)
{
    return 37;
}

__attribute__ ((destructor)) void after_main(void)
{
    int exit_code = get_exit_code(); // Always zero
    printf("Exit code is %d\n", exit_code);
}
```

Comment: How do you know that the exit code has been set in between the return from main and the call to your *destructor*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destructors are run as part of the process exit - when you return from `main()` (or by calling `exit()`, etc), the destructors are called.
So at the time you read `/proc/self/stat` the process is still alive and `/proc/self/stat` is not updated yet. Because `exit_code` in `/proc/self/stat` gets updated as a result of the call to `_exit` (or equivalent call made to kernel) system call. But that doesn't happen until all the destructors/exit handlers are run by the C library; it's made as the as the last call as part of running exit handlers. `exit_code` from `/proc/self/stat` is really meant for `wait(2)` calls which the kernel provides to the its parent process. What this means is that there's no way to get exit code from `/proc/self/stat` from the process itself from user space.

What you could do instead is use [`on_exit`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/on_exit.3.html) (non standard glibc function). This will give you the return code on normal program termination.
You'll also need to interpose `_exit` so that you have a chance to get the return code when in other cases e.g., `_exit` called from a signal handler. Note that it's not always possible to get the return code this way e.g., the process gets killed by `SIGTERM` or `SIGKILL`.

Comment: I are already interposing _exit in order to call the destructor ourselves.

Comment: There's also `__attribute__((destructor))` attribute. If you use, the destructors will be called (you don't need to call your destructor functions explicitly via `_exit` interposing). But that mechanism doesn't allow you capture the exit code as noted already.